# 'Hello Xamarin Forms' Android App - how to get it to work targeting JellyBean 18 (4.3)?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, javabeans, jelly

I need to target the `Android JellyBean` (4.3) platform for a project. Having Xamarin Forms installed, I download the `4.3 SDK`, create a new Xamarin Forms PCL project. Right-click the .Droid project and set Compile, Minimum and Target Android versions to Android 4.3 (`API Level 18 - Jelly Bean`). Hit build and get this compilation error:

> Error  1   No resource identifier found for attribute 'touchscreenBlocksFocus' in package 'android'    E:\Users\Toby\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\M3SLM10\TestM3\M3slm10\M3slm10\M3slm10.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\2FCCE52AFB6F854A55FA951FA3C83F6E\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml 28  M3slm10.Droid

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: When I remove the line causing the error and hit rebuild, I end up with more errors - even in places that don't appear to be in my project - .java files, etc, etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only be setting your `Minimum SDK` to API 18. Your `Compile SDK` or `TargetFramework` should be set to the latest API installed (API 23). That way any resources can be compiled for Xamarin.Forms.

There's a great resource on this here:

http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/

Comment: The requirements are also documented here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Android